# How to draw a line with one bending end

Tags: android, line, selector

[image: ow]

How can I draw such a horizontal line (bending upward from the left end) as shown in the above image in the XML file through a selector? below is my selector file code. Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/md_black_1000" />
<solid

    android:color="#ffffff"
    />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="15px"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15px"
    />

<padding
    android:top="3dp"
    android:bottom="3dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this effect only for specific cases, for example, when you had fixed item height:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetTop="-2dp"
    android:insetRight="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Item"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And then:

[image]